# Thymeleaf submit ignores list of objects

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

Given a class looking like this:

```
public class Foo {
    private List<Bar> bars = new ArrayList<>();

    //getter and setter
}
```

Initialized with either an empty list, or with values added and then appended to the spring model in the controller like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "add")
public String add(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("foo", new Foo());        
    return "foos/add";
}
```

When that same model attribute is submitted back to another controller method looking like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "add", params = {"addBar"})
public String addBar(@ModelAttribute("foo") Foo foo) {
    // Here foo.getBars() is always null....
    // all other properties are correctly initialized
    return "foos/add";
}
```

the bar collection is always null. Every other property has the correct value except for the collection which is always null.

I verified that the model has it's collection while rendering with:

```
<div>
    <p>DEBUG</p>
    <pre data-th-text="${foo.bars}" />
</div>
```

which prints `[]` when I create an empty `Foo` instance or if I pre-fill the instance with some `Bar`s, I see something along the lines of `[Bar@1234]`.

Currently in the html itself `Bar`s are not bound anywhere so nothing should affect them.

What am I doing wrong? Does submit only send values bound with `th:field` and not everything in the rendered model attribute?

Answer (score 1):

Correct, submit only binds those variables bound with `th:field`.  The easiest solution to this is to add `@SessionAttributes("foo")` onto your controller:

```
@Controller
@SessionAttributes("foo")
public class FooController {
```

That way attributes not `POST`ed are still set in your model object.